# Colab + Drive: import keys + sharing notebooks

Tags: key, google-colaboratory, drive

When I import a key from Google Drive in a shared Colab notebook by mounting the drive and using with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/API/keys.csv"), can everyone who executes the shared notebook also import this key? (Does sharing a notebook automatically share the associated folder on Google Drive?)

What's the advantage of storing the keys as "secrets" (on the left bar in colab)? Can everyone in a shared notebook use this secret key, or just the original creator of the notebook?